# why is my rigid body object not falling correctly?

Tags: physics

I have a model of a cup that I want to fall on the ground. The issue is that once it hits the ground it doesn't rotate or anything so only the rim of the cup is making contact with my passive object. [video](https://gfycat.com/fewuntidyhousefly)

[Here's the blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_8kz8UJ7AgqTy2_NyW17LjP3ybMiG1Ed/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: maybe in the physics settings check the Collisions > Shape? maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots I've added the file. I've tried both a mesh and a convex hull for the shape and it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cup object has been scaled down a lot, apply the scale:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to apply the scale, I think I need to go to sleep. Thank you!